# Is it possible to disable the LargeFile Vim plugin for certain filetypes?

Tags: vim

I am mostly happy with the LargeFile plugin, but have recently had a need to selectively disable it for a specific filetype. The LargeFile plugin disables the `FileType` event; and the filetype in question is determined from the file contents, not the file extension, so I need to use the `BufReadPost` event like so:

```
au BufReadPost * if &ft == "myfiletype" | let g:LargeFile=100 | endif
```

But setting `g:LargeFile` has no effect there. I also tried calling the `:Unlarge` command with no effect. How can I disable the LargeFile plugin or modify its settings based on the filetype?

Answer (score 0):

Your auto-command does not work because at the moment of its execution
the filetype of the current buffer is not detected yet. If the target
filetype can be deduced from the filename, use an auto-command pattern
instead of testing against the filetype.

Here is an example for C files:

```
autocmd BufRead *.c Unlarge
```

If the filename pattern detection is not sufficient, manually trigger
the filetype detection first:

```
autocmd BufRead *.c
\   if !did_filetype() | filetype detect | endif |
\   if &ft is# 'c' | Unlarge | endif
```